# Get footer div to sit at bottom of page

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

I have a footer which typically I would like to sit at the bottom of my page at all times. This would be easy enough except I have another div layered on top of the page. Here are two screencasts:

- One with the footer as it is currently behaving:
  https://youtu.be/NVugCv3AbXQ
- One without the footer:
  https://youtu.be/Z3RIon3mA_I

I have tried:

1. giving the container div a negative `margin-bottom` set to the height of the footer
2. Using fixed/absolute positioning with `bottom: 0`
3. Using javascript to force desired behaviour

How can I get the footer to recognize the "foremost" div and be placed at the bottom of this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `z-index`? just be sure `z-index` will work only when a `position` is declared.

Comment: yup `z-index` was set with `fixed` position.  that expectedly sets it 'closest' to the viewer but doesn't dock it at the bottom.

Comment: I don't know if I understand the problem, but you could put the whole page in a single div or iframe and have the footer below. Could you put some of your css/html?

Comment: Does your `<html>` and `<body>` elements have a declared `height`?
For example: `html, body { height: 100%; }`

Comment: Yeah I've set height for `html` and `body` to 100%